# Select SQL results grouped by year

Tags: sql

How can I get results grouped by every 2 years?

Table 1:
ORDERS

```
 ORDER_ID       MemberID   OrderDate
+----------+--------------+-----+
 1          a              05-06-2016
 2          b              06-06-2016 
 3          a              06-06-2017
 4          b              07-06-2017
 5          h              08-06-2017
 6          a              02-06-2018
 7          b              03-06-2018
 8          a              05-06-2019
 9          b              09-06-2019
```

Expected Output Results:

```
  YEAR      ORDERS_AMOUNT   
+----------+--------------+
 2016-2017          5              
 2018-2019          4
```

I'm using the following query, but obvs it's not working...

```
SELECT year( o.orderDate) as Year, 
    count(o.order_id) as Order_Count
FROM orders  o 
Group by o.orderDate
```

Comment: What is your database, sql is a common language.

Comment: how order_amount column is calulated? or what does it has?

Comment: What would happen if there is a gap in years? Say there is no sale in 2020, but there are sales in 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Group By** of Year(orderDate)/2

```
SELECT  (CONVERT(VARCHAR,MIN(year(OrderDate)))+'-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX(year(OrderDate)))) AS [Year],
        COUNT(*) as [ORDERS_AMOUNT]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY FLOOR(Year(OrderDate) /2)
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The `floor` is not needed if you are using SQL Server. As integer division yields integer too. However, putting floor won't hurt either, as it will work on RDBMS that yields decimal for integer division. SQL Server test: `select OrderDate, year(OrderDate) / 2 as x, floor(year(OrderDate) / 2) as y, convert(numeric, year(OrderDate)) / 2 as with_decimals
from orders` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b141dbf4ef836487664a26b7d3c7cc95

Comment: Excellent approach for converstion purpose into != sources. Thxs @MichaelBuen

Answer (score 1):

You have to group according to the `year(orderDate)/2`

```
SELECT (year(orderDate)/2) * 2 as Year, 
       count(o.order_id) as Order_Count
FROM orders  o 
Group by year(orderDate)/2
```

This will work in SQL Server, in some other DBMS you may need to round the `year(orderDate)/2` result. I omit the formatting of the year interval since it is trivial and very DBMS specific.

Answer (score 1):

Radim's solution is almost correct, but it need to use integer division for MySQL. `/` would just yield the same year as the original year when run on MySQL.

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pW4YduNY8DJDy6GCLKUdqS/0

```
SELECT 
    year(orderDate) div 2 * 2 as Year, 
    count(o.order_id) as Order_Count       
FROM orders  o 
Group by year
```

Another approach, use modulo:

```
SELECT 
    year(orderDate) - mod(year(orderdate),2) as year,
    count(o.order_id) as Order_Count       
FROM orders  o 
Group by year
```

Output on both queries above:

```
| year | Order_Count |
| ---- | ----------- |
| 2016 | 5           |
| 2018 | 4           |
```

Radim's SQL Server code would not work on MySQL:

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pW4YduNY8DJDy6GCLKUdqS/3

```
SELECT (year(orderDate)/2) * 2 as Years, 
       count(o.order_id) as Order_Count
FROM orders  o 
Group by (year(orderDate)/2) * 2
```

Output:

```
| Years | Order_Count |
| ----- | ----------- |
| 2016  | 2           |
| 2017  | 3           |
| 2018  | 2           |
| 2019  | 2           |
```

It would work on SQL Server though.

Live test:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ced41544d5727fb02229a17efc6970c3

Output:

```
the_year    Order_Count
2016        5
2018        4
```

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    year(orderDate) - (year(orderdate) % 2) as year,
    count(o.order_id) as Order_Count       
FROM orders  o 
Group by year(orderDate) - (year(orderdate) % 2)
```

Output:

```
 year   Order_Count
 2016   5
 2018   4
```

Comment: It looks like  'mod' does not work in SQL at least for this query. But Thanks! I'm going to steal the resource: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: SQL Server's mod is similar to C, Java, C#, etc. It uses `%` operator

`SELECT 
    year(orderDate) - (year(orderdate) % 2) as year,
    count(o.order_id) as Order_Count       
FROM orders  o 
Group by year(orderDate) - (year(orderdate) % 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.

SQL-Server

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Count,
       Concat(Min(Year(orderdate)), '-', Min(Year(orderdate) + 1)) AS Year
FROM   ORDERS
GROUP  BY Year(orderdate) / 2
```

MySQL

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Count,
       Concat(Min(Year(orderdate)), '-', Min(Year(orderdate) + 1)) AS Year
FROM   orders
GROUP  BY Year(orderdate) DIV 2
```

<sup>Thank you, [Michael Buen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11432/michael-buen) for suggesting [MySQL DIV Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_div.asp).</sup>

Comment: Upvoted for succinct code. It works on SQL Server. It's good that there's no need to multiply it back to 2 :) Be mindful that your exact code won't work on MySQL. Its `/` always yield decimal poitns. Use `div` instead to get integer result from division, that is if you are using MySQL.

Comment: Your code on MySQL produces invalid result. Just need minor correction, change the `/` to `div`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pW4YduNY8DJDy6GCLKUdqS/5

Comment: @MichaelBuen, thank you for suggesting that. I have updated the answer.